# Monitor not detected at startup, only if I unplug and reconnect it

Tags: macbook-pro, display, catalina

This question has been asked in many flavors but couldn't find mine. The external monitor for my MBP (2019 Catalina) is a Philips PHL 276C8. I use its USB-C connector to charge my MBP as well.

The issue I have is the display does not get detected at startup; the computer is charging but no display is seen. If I unplug the cable from the MBP and reconnect it, everything works - both charging and monitor.

I am curious if there is some known workaround for this and grateful for any pointer.